# function.class() does not apply to given class

Tags: r, oop, function

I need a little help with this code:

```
foo <- function(obj){
  "fail"
}

foo.usefull <- function(obj){
  obj$content
}

myob <- structure(list(content="sucess"), class="usefull")

foo(myob)
#[1] "fail"
```

What the call of `foo(myob)`should return ist "success". But it seems like I am missing something. What?

Comment: +1 one concrete question with working example code!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still have to register `foo` as a generic function for you to be able to use `foo.usefull` as a generic. See [this post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-s3-oop-system/) for the way how to do this. For your code:

```
foo <- function(x) UseMethod("foo", x)   # define generic
foo.usefull <- function(obj){
  obj$content
}
myob <- structure(list(content="sucess"), class="usefull")
foo(myob)
# [1] "sucess"
```

For other generic's such as `print` or `plot` this has already been done, and there just defining a new `plot.blabla` works right away.

Comment: Thanks. But out of curiosity: How can I keep my generic `foo` which applies to everything else but the class `usefull`?

Comment: Use a `foo.default`, which then the default if no specific implementation is found.